# What is the difference between `each` and `map` enumerators?

Tags: ruby

Examining the following code

```
[1,2,3,4].map # => #<Enumerator: [1, 2, 3, 4]:map> 
[1,2,3,4].each # => #<Enumerator: [1, 2, 3, 4]:each>
```

we can see that both are an enumerator. One is `map` and other is `each`. The method `to_enum` also returns an enumerator `each`. Is there any difference between these two enumerators?

Comment: @Ian agree, sorry about this.

Comment: No problem. I just found a question basically the same as yours so I thought I'd point it out :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, when you iterate over the map enumerator, it will take the result and populate it into a new array:

```
[1,2,3,4].map.each { |n| n * 2 }  # => [2, 4, 6, 8]
```

When you iterate over the each enumerator, it will return the original array

```
[1,2,3,4].each.each { |n| n * 2 }  # => [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Map exists to take an array of one type and convert it to an array of a different type, each exists to simply iterate over the array (doing something with a side effect for each element, such as printing it out).